# how i fix cryptodisk not found in grub

Tags: boot, grub2, grubrescue

please guys help me in this problem!

i install ubuntu on full encryption system.

and the i remove the passphrase of the harddrive.

i ise that command:

```
cryptsetup luksRemoveKey /dev/sda2
```

but when i reboot my laptop it asks for the passphrase and when i entering it it show me an error in grub.

this error is:

```
error : access denied
error : no cryptodisk found.
error : 'cryptouuid/74hu6edi854..' not found

grub rescue >
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It looks like you locked your house and threw away the key. Now you can't enter the house. You may have to install Ubuntu again.

Comment: ... and do not trow away the key.

Answer (score 0):

LUKS encryption uses one key.  The key is randomly generated when the LUKS disk is formatted.  The key never changes.

The key is itself encrypted, typically with a passphrase.

(Alternatively, multiple passphrases may be used.  If multiple passphrases are used, any single one of the passphrases can decrypt the key.  Once the key is decrypted, the key is used to access the actual data on the LUKS disk.)

Typically, the encrypted copy(ies) of the key is (are) stored on the LUKS disk itself, in the LUKS header.  However, if you wish, you could also store the (probably encrypted) LUKS key somewhere other than in the LUKS header.  For example, you could store it in a separate USB disk.

The command `cryptsetup luksRemoveKey /dev/sda2` prompts you for a passphrase.  `cryptsetup` will see if the passphrase can decrypt any of the encrypted copies of the key.  If yes, then that encrypted copy of the key is removed (i.e. deleted).  Consequently, that passphrase can no longer decrypt the key, with the following further consequence: that passphrase can no longer be used to access the disk.  So `luksRemoveKey` retires the provided passphrase.

If you retire the only passphrase, then the data on the disk is lost forever.  (Unless you previously backed-up the LUKS key on another disk.)

In your case, running `cryptsetup luksRemoveKey /dev/sda2` probably deleted the only existing encrypted copy of the key.  Consequently, you will almost certainly never again be able to access the data in `/dev/sda2`.

You will probably need to reformat `/dev/sda2` and start again.

The closest you can come to removing the encryption from a LUKS encrypted disk is to add the empty string as a passphrase.  However, it appears that Ubuntu 22.04 will silently refuse to attempt to use an empty passphrase to decrypt a LUKS encrypted root filesystem, even though it is entirely valid to encrypt a LUKS disk with an empty passphrase.  (Some people might consider it to be a bug that Ubuntu 22.04 silently refuses to use an empty passphrase.)